# Custom metadata type records - Getting deleted in the subscriber org

Tags: custom-metadata

I have created a custom metadata type with 'Public' visibility at the metadata level but restricting the access to 'Upgradable' on the record level.

I managed package it and installed it in the subscriber org.When I try to edit the record & change the 'Protected Component' checkbox to 'Checked', it displays the message 'Insufficient access' which is as expected but ends up deleting the record.

Is it a known issue? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you changing the 'Protected Component' checkbox to 'Checked' in the developer org or in the subscriber org?

Comment: subscriber org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. The record you updated is not deleted, but marked protected, so you don't have a visibility to it in your subscriber org.

To workaround this, you can install an upgrade version of the package, it will bring that record back and make it public again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir. I have watched a lot of your videos. Thanks for the knowledge you are sharing with the community. Any timelines on when this would be fixed? We are seriously considering CMD types for our project. We are building an application with very tight timelines on upgrades to the package. I clearly understand why new/updated mdt records cannot be patched as they are metadata themselves & must go in the full versioned package, but is there any plan of allowing them as a patch in future. What are the plans for supporting workflow/formulas, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: another question, Vladimir. Is it possible to create a cmd type of the packaging org(ex: namespace :pckg__) from the subscriber org from within the managed package code? So, if I have a button on the VF page in the managed package to create a new mdt record of type pckg__cmd(that of the packaging org namespace). Is it possible assuming the cmd type has Public access and fields are editable on subscriber's side? I did a POC with a negative output for this. Would like if you confirm it, please.

Comment: @ShaliniSF We are going to address this bug in Summer '18 (forward looking statement) with a possibility that it will be backported to Spring '18.
Please reach out to me on LinkedIn on Twitter, I'm happy to answer your other questions as they are not related to the original topic.